# Passing Variable from javascript to php using wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

At the top of my code I do have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then my functions which implement google maps api

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        alert(lng + ' ' +lat);
        nearLocation();
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Function above calls near location

```
function nearLocation()
{
    alert("hi");
    var userID = "Hello";
                //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'script.php',
                    data: "userID=" + userID,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!");
                    }
    });
}
```

and in my script.php I have

```
<?php
$uid = isset($_POST['userID']);
?>
```

but success alert does not display any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to script.php you're not getting any output. You've only declared a variable, you never sent any output back to the AJAX request you've sent.

Change script.php to this.

```
<?php
$uid = isset($_POST['userID']);
echo $uid;
```

On success in your javascript, add console.log(data) to review the response from the server. Now there are better ways of doing this such as returning json but this should solve your problem.

Side note: The closing php tag '?>' is not needed in a file containing only php. It's best practice to omit it to avoid unwanted whitespace.

Comment: Sorry but still no success alert pops up after I add the code that you gave in. I do however understand what you meant. Is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Yup as soon as the geocode button is clicked it is being invoked